# Saving an Iterable of a Spring Data Cassandra entity yields exception

Tags: spring-data, spring-data-cassandra

I have a very simple Groovy entity annotated with Spring Data Cassandra annotations. I've written a repo that is based on the CrudRepository interface. In my unit test, I'm testing the various methods in the repo, using Cassandra Unit and Spring Test. All the other methods in the interface that I'm testing seem to work fine. I can insert, delete, search etc from my application using the annotated entity. But when I try to save an Iterable of the entity through the repo, it fails with the following exception:

```
org.springframework.data.cassandra.mapping.VerifierMappingExceptions: java.util.ArrayList:
Cassandra entities must have the @Table, @Persistent or @PrimaryKeyClass Annotation

at org.springframework.data.cassandra.mapping.BasicCassandraPersistentEntityMetadataVerifier.verify(BasicCassandraPersistentEntityMetadataVerifier.java:45)
at org.springframework.data.cassandra.mapping.BasicCassandraPersistentEntity.verify(BasicCassandraPersistentEntity.java:198)
at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.addPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:317)
at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.getPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:179)
at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.getPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:139)
at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.getPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:66)
at org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.CassandraTemplate.getTableNamndraTemplate.java:217)
at org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.CassandraTemplate.doInsert(CassandraTemplate.java:641)
at org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.CassandraTemplate.insert(CassandraTemplate.java:237)
at org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.CassandraTemplate.insert(CassandraTemplate.java:232)
at x.y.z.repositories.UserRepositoryImpl.save(UserRepositoryImpl.java:44)
at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:718)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:653)
at x.y.z.repositories.UserDataRepositorySpec.verify saving a list(UserDataRepositorySpec.groovy:186)
```

So, saving, deleting, or modifying a single entity instance works fine, but as soon as I create a List (backed by an ArrayList), it fails with this error. The entity itself looks something like this:

```
@InheritConstructors
@EqualsAndHashCode
@ToString
@Table("user_data")
class UserData {
  @PrimaryKey("id")
  long userId
  @Column
  String name
}
```

It seems counter intuitive that I would have to create a special type of List just to save a collection of entities. Am I missing something? I'm using Spring Cassandra 1.3.4 with the DataStax driver core 2.1.9. Thanks.

Comment: Could you post some code how you invoke the `save` method with a list? A reproducible test case (gist) would be great.

Comment: This might seem like a dumb question, but are you certain that you have the right `@Table` annotation on your `(Cassandra)PersistentEntity` class, "_UserData_" (i.e. `org.springframework.data.cassandra.mapping.Table`).  The only reason I ask is, SD Cassandra doesn't seem to be recognizing your `@Table("user_data")` annotation.  See... https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-cassandra/blob/master/spring-data-cassandra/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/cassandra/mapping/BasicCassandraPersistentEntityMetadataVerifier.java#L57-L77

Comment: And in particular... https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-cassandra/blob/master/spring-data-cassandra/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/cassandra/mapping/BasicCassandraPersistentEntityMetadataVerifier.java#L73-L77

Comment: Hi @JohnBlum. Yes, all the other operations on the repo class work fine, it's only the save(Iterable<UserData> that is not working. The CQL looks like this:

    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS data.user_data (
   id bigint,
   name text, 
   PRIMARY KEY(id)
   );

Comment: @mp911de I'll do that, but it will probably take me a day or two.